# How to burn a DVD from within GParted Live CD?

Tags: linux, gparted

I made the mistaking of using GParted to repartition my hard drive before making sure I have an OS reinstall disk ready. I have the iso somewhere in the hard drive.

How can I burn a DVD from this ISO, from the GParted Live CD?

Answer (score 4):

Start Gparted-Live in X graphical mode (the default).
Gparted-Live provides you with a *Terminal , a *Web Browser*, and *Network* connectivity via the Network config icon (typically by using DHCP).

The first thing you need to do is establish a Network connection.

Next, install a CD/DVD burning CLI app. For your situation, `wodim` can burn your *.iso* to an optical disk... In the browser, downonload `wodim` .deb package from

```
http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/wodim
```

Next, open a terminal, and run the following command to install it.

```
sudo dpkg -i wodim*.deb
```

To burn your .iso, you typically need to know the CD/DVD burner's device specs/ID.  You can use `wodim --devices` to find it, or,  according to `man wodim`:

> As  a  special exception, the device specification can  be -1 or just
>   omitted, which invokes automatic guessing of an appropriate device for
>   the selected operation

Also according to `man wodim`

> If no speed value could be found, wodim uses a drive specific default
>   speed.

To burn your `distro.iso` to disk, run this command (speed=4 is just an example):

```
sudo wodim -v -eject speed=4 /path/to/distro.iso
```

---

*Note:*   To find the *distro.iso*, you will need to identify and mount the partition on which it is located.., To list all partitions:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Next, you need a directory to mount it to.  Make one in `/tmp`

```
mkdir /tmp/myiso
```

To mount the partiton `/dev/sda1` (for example):

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1  /tmp/myiso
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I'll try to apply it tonight when I get home.

Comment: The package link above seems dead. I installed the deb file without error from https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=wodim Make sure the deb matches the architecture and version those of your Gparted.